# DISM / SQL2012 unable to access Windows Update when ran by chef-client

Tags: sql-server-2012, chef-infra, windows-server-2012, winrm

My question is this: is there a permissions issue of some kind when running chef through WinRM that doesnt allow programs to go out to the internet?

I'm trying to use Chef 11.4.4 on Server 2012 Std to deploy SQL 2012 Std. I've run into two problems and I believe they're related:

```
windows_feature "NetFx3" do
  action :install
end
```

This fails as DISM is supposed to go to microsoft update and download the .Net 3.5.1 files. It works fine if I run `DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart` manually through RDP - which is basically what the windows_feature runs.

If I run `DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs` through a recipe (with the DVD in), it works. Effectively, this bypasses the need to go online to download the files.

The second problem is SQL Server 2012 setup tries to go online looking for updates during install. If I add the /UpdateEnabled=false switch to the install command, it proceeds. I'm using

```
windows_package "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit)" do
  source "\\\\10.200.1.240\\admin\\Installs\\SQL\\SQL2012Std\\setup.exe"
  timeout 3600 # 60min to just install sql will be fine. Default of 10min can be a bit short
  action :install
  installer_type :custom
  options "/ConfigurationFile=\"#{node['mssql']['installIni']}\" /SAPWD=\"#{node['mssql']['sapw']}\""
end
```

In the installIni file, I have a setting of `UpdateSource=MU`.

I'm running chef via `knife winrm 192.168.170.145 'chef-client -c c:/chef/client.rb' -m -x nfox` if that makes a difference. I do not have this problem when I run `chef-client` from an administrator:cmd window.

Comment: Short answer: Yes WinRM has limitations around network access, but usually we're bitten on network share access and the idea is to use CredSSP. The usual way to circumvent winrm limitations is to configure chef as a scheduled task and to start a run of this scheduled task with `knife winrm ... 'schtasks /Run /TN <chef client task name>'`

Comment: Finally found the command line parameter, anothe option is to launch chef-client via `winrs` with the additional `-authentication:CredSSP` parameter, with CredSSP configured on the remote target [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309365(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, winrm (chef's communication protocol) doesn't have full user "context" as compared to if you were executing commands locally (even when doing this as a local admin-privileged user or local Administrator).

The solution as was mentioned before is to use scheduled tasks, which fire on the machine asynchronously. This has the benefit of having full context, but drawback that you need to know when scheduled task completes to delete it and proceed. As far as using scheduled tasks you should use the windows cookbook that has lwrp's for them.

So ... the solution for the NetFx3 feature install (solution to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (64-bit) install can be done using same scheduled task approach):

- catch the error (this will happen only on the very first run of the
  recipe; runs after feature is installed won't throw the error) and
  handle it in a scheduled task; error handling in chef is a lengthy
  topic, but in a nutshell you can only catch chef errors during the
  "compile" phase of the chef run, that's what the end.run_action(
  :install ) is doing)
- create and run scheduled task
- poll until the feature is installed OR you exceed the timeout
- always delete the task regardless of success or failure installing the feature
- proceed based on successful/failed feature installation

Create COOKBOOK/files/default/install_dotnetfx3.bat.erb that contains

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart
```

and then have this as part of your recipe

```
begin
  windows_feature "NetFx3ServerFeatures" do
    action :nothing
  end.run_action( :install )

  windows_feature "NetFx3" do
    action :nothing
  end.run_action( :install )

rescue Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed => ex

  Chef::Log.error( "ShellCommandFailed was thrown during windows_feature NetFx3 install. Kicking off install via windows_task." )

  install_dotnet3_task   = 'install_dotnetfx3'
  install_dotnet3_script = 'C:\Chef\install_dotnetfx3.bat'

  # :create cookbook_file in "compile" phase
  cookbook_file install_dotnet3_script do
    source 'install_dotnetfx3.bat.erb'
    action :nothing
  end.run_action( :create )

  # :create windows_task in "compile" phase
  windows_task install_dotnet3_task do
    user Administrator
    password XXXXXXX
    command install_dotnet3_script 
    run_level :highest
    action :nothing  
    frequency :minute
    frequency_modifier 10
  end.run_action( :create )

  # :run windows_task in "compile" phase
  windows_task install_dotnet3_task do
    action :nothing
  end.run_action( :run )

  featureInstalled = false
  iteration = 0
  # number of sleeps each sleep_period seconds (total_sleep_period =     max_dotnet3_install_via_task_loop_counter * sleep_period)
  max_dotnet3_install_via_task_loop_counter = 10
  sleep_period = 20 # in sec
  loop do

    # Check if feature is installed
    featureInstalled = shell_out( "dism /online /get-featureinfo /FeatureName:NetFx3 | find \"State : Enabled\"" ).exitstatus == 0 
    break if featureInstalled || ( iteration += 1 ) > max_dotnet3_install_via_task_loop_counter

    # sleep for sleep_period seconds
    sleep sleep_period

    log "Inside of polling loop for installation (taking #{(iteration * sleep_period)} seconds) of feature via windows_task." do
      level :info
      action :nothing
    end.run_action( :write )
  end

  # Always :delete windows_task (so that it won't fire again with frequency above) in "compile" phase regardless of whether 
  # installation via task succeeded or failed.
  windows_task install_dotnet3_task do
    action :nothing
  end.run_action( :delete )

  if featureInstalled
    log "Installation of the feature via windows_task succeeded." do
      level :info
      action :nothing
    end.run_action( :write )
  else
    # Raise exception if installation via windows_task failed
    raise "Installation of the feature via windows_task timed out within #{(max_dotnet3_install_via_task_loop_counter * sleep_period)} seconds. Try increasing install_via_task_max_poll_counter attribute and re-try."
  end
end
```

Comment: That sounds crazy to me... Better do the install in an idempotent way and let chef run from a sched taks (on a regular basis or not), but creating multiple sched tasks sounds clearly looking for problems...

Comment: Only one schedule task is created, run and deleted (regardless of success or failure).

Comment: Which is far far away of the idempotent behavior a configuration management system aim to enforce (i.e. You can't be sure of the system state at end)

Comment: The very first time above runs, it will throw the exception, which will be caught, and feature installed via windows_task. Thereafter (if above is run again and again), the exception won't be thrown since the feature was installed. Idempotency is achieved.

Comment: Nope, as you assume that the scheduled task will be successful, you can't guarantee the install was really done...

Comment: You yourself suggested using scheduled tasks. Although your suggestion on using them is different, as you are suggesting scheduling chef-client run itself in a scheduled task, and then invoking it via "knife winrm ...".

Comment: Yep, and thus using an idempotent code exactly the same for each run of the chef client, the schedule task is just a workaround the credssp need within Winrm, in use with old unsupported system as win2k3 not able to handle credssp configuration (and used from NT4 era for remote execution with impersonalisation  to be honest with my old school learnings)

Comment: Don't take me bad, you answer is interesting but promote a 'bad behavior' I did not Downvote as it's interesting in the manner, but I can't upvote as the way it is used is a bad behavior in my opinion. I just warn in comment about why I find it a bad behavior.

Comment: Fair enough. It's convenient to run all the recipes together as part of one chef run (ex. knife bootstrap with list of recipes), so you can't easily break out some to run with "knife winrm ..." separately, unless your workflow/CI allows for that or you already do that anyways.